# Teamcity, prevent cleaning folders outside the checkout folder

Tags: svn, teamcity

I'm using teamcity 9.1.with custom [checkout directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpwvX.jpg)
 inside in agent's working directory ( for example `C:\BuildAgent\work\branch\rootFolder\checOutFolder` )
But I need to [create few folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X778X.jpg) in parent folder 'branch'.

They are successfully created but deleted in the end of build configuration on agent.
Also in teamcity-agent.log I found:

```
[2016-06-05 14:44:35,776]   INFO - rectories.DirectoryCleanerImpl - Won't delete C:\BuildAgent\work\branch\rootFolder\checOutFolder
[2016-06-05 14:44:35,776]   INFO - ies.DirectoryMapUnknownCleaner - Checking not listed in directory.map folder C:\BuildAgent\work\branch\JClassSCC. 
[2016-06-05 14:44:35,778]   INFO - rectories.DirectoryCleanerImpl - Move directory C:\BuildAgent\work\JClassSCC to C:\BuildAgent\work\.old\JClassSCC_0 for cleaning 
[2016-06-05 14:44:35,778]   INFO - l.directories.DirectoryMapImpl - Cleaning up old checkout directories. Default lifetime = 192 hour(s)
```

How to prevent removing files and folders from `%teamcity.agent.work.dir%` that are not directly in checkout directory.
Thanx.

Comment: Simply put - if I set custom checkout path somewhere inside %teamcity.agent.work.dir%, and create or copy files and folders somewhere between %teamcity.agent.work.dir% and custom path - everything except custom files path is cleaned.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by setting 'branch' folder as a Custom checkout path. And adding checkout rule: +:. => rootFolder/checOutFolder. In this case everything in 'branch' is kept.

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity agent assumes ownership over it's "work" directory, so it is not a good idea to create sub-directories there.

You can specify custom checkout directory outside the agent's work (in a directory completely unrelated to the TeamCity agent). This way only the content of the directory itself will be modified by the TeamCity agent. Obviously, you will need to manage the directory (e.g. delete when it is no longer needed) from your scripts/manually.

Actually, storing data on the machine and using that across builds is a bad pattern. You will need to address consistency, directory cleanup, etc. not to mention that you never can be sure what was the state files during the build. It is highly recommended to rework your build procedure to either check out the files from the version control or download as artifact of another build.